# yum install php5-sybase. "No Package Available"

Tags: centos6, unixodbc

I try to connect mssql in centos, so I need odbc freetds,unixodbc I have all I need to install dblib at last, I type "yum install php5-sysbase" command in terminal and here is the response:
[image]

how can I install php5-sybase ?

Answer (score 0):

in centos, you run:

```
yum install php-mssql
```

then in /etc/php.ini, add the following:

```
extension=mssql.so
```